# PHP preg_match search for specific pattern

Tags: php, preg-match

I am not familiar with the syntax of preg_match and want to find following pattern within a string.

- The substring must start with `M` or `L` (M|L + white space)
- It ends with an white space
- between that there is a number, separated by a `,` and both sides of the `,` the length of the number is 1-3 character

Can somebody help me with that?

example-string:

```
<path d="M 584,363 L 584,364 L 582,365 />
```

Comment: what you want to fetch?

Comment: see : http://rubular.com/r/Q0UUqbcbWv

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all( '~[ML]\s+[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3}~i', $str, $mats );
print_r( $mats );
```

The i flag after the regEx means case insensitive, change that if desired.

Answer (score 0):

How about [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('/(\b[ML]\s+\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\s+)/', $string, $match);
```

Comment: I just solved it myself: preg_match_all( '/[ML]\s[0-9]*,[0-9]*/s',...)

Comment: @user3744885: Your regex matches also: `XYZM 123456789,`